# Extending allocation of another new expression

Tags: c++, memory-management

Section 5.3.4/10 of N3797 said:

> An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global
>   allocation function (18.6.1.1, 18.6.1.2). When it does so, the storage
>   is instead provided by the implementation or provided by extending the
>   allocation of another new-expression.

What does mean by extending? That is, we have amount of storage allocated by new expression `e1` (assume that it is 4 bytes). Let implementation omits to call an allocation function in new-expression `e2` and the storage provides by extending the allocation of e1. How does it affect to the storage provided by e1? Whether addresses provided to object `o1` created by `e1` and object `o2` created by `e2` intersects?

Comment: They obviously could not intersect.

Comment: Where do you see this quote?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So what does extending the allocation mean?

Comment: @Dmitry: Depends. I imagine it's just as it says; you ask for 32 bytes for your own object, and in the background 64 bytes are allocated instead, with 32 of those being used for the other thing instead.

Comment: @Brian I'm sorry. I've updated my Q.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is, an implementation determines before the allocation whether the allocation be extended or no?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Well, yeah, how else would it work? Divine pixie magic?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It might work in any way, because it doesn't explicitly specify in the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit By the way, what is the point of extending the allocation? Does it give an additional performance?

Comment: I think this passage has been added to allow merging multiple allocations. Each call is (potentially) expensive, so you try to avoid them by allocating more memory than you need at a first allocation, and using it for multiple different objects each of which the user has requested an (individual) allocation for. This might also be related to the (optional) garbage collection features.

Comment: Different objects are still guaranteed to have different addresses; however an allocation function can re-use an address of a released (freed/deleted) object.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [N3664](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html) introduced this concept of merging allocations.

Comment: @dyp That is, there is no restriction to that objects have the same type. It is completely arbitrary objects.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Essentially, it allows rewriting `int* p0 = new int; double* p1 = new double;` as `char* buf = new char[sizeof(int) + sizeof(double)]; int* p0 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf+sizeof(double)); double* p1 = reinterpret_cast<double*>(buf+0);` (plus code that deals with alignment).